# Login form expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, expo

i'm creating a login form on expo right now i have this in ./screens/HomeOneScreen.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';

export default function HomeOneScreen() {
  const [email, onChangeText] = React.useState('Email');
  const [password, onChangeText]= React.useState('Password');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
        style={{width: 200, height:40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={text=> onChangeText(text)}
        email={email}
    /><Text>{email}</Text>
    <TextInput
        style={{width: 200, height:40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={text=> onChangeText(text)}
        password={password}
    />
    <Text>{password}</Text>
      <View style={styles.separator} lightColor="#eee" darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: '80%',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
marginBottom: 10,
  },
    instructions: {
        color: '#888',
        fontSize: 18,
        marginHorizontal: 15,
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: "cyan",
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    buttongreen: {
        backgroundColor: "lime",
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    buttonyellow: {
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#000',
    },
});
```

But looks like it does not liking my double onChangeText :
Identifier 'onChangeText' has already been declared.

When i replace onChangeText by onChangeText2 on password field the app is loading but the password is not recognized in the print variable password.

Where and how can i put the password field?

Answer (score 0):

Found it replacing onChangeText by onChangeText2 exept here:

```
    <TextInput
        style={{width: 200, height:40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={text=> onChangeText2(text)}
        password={password}
    />
```